# Word for Overriding Auto-Correct

Tags: word-request, verbs

I was having an email conversation with friends about glyphosate. One friend consistently misspelled the word as glyphosphate*. In order to bring this to his attention, I replied, "It's spelled glyphosate, not glyphosphate." After typing this, my phone auto-corrected glyphosphate to glyphosate. I then had to manually type in the extra letters to misspell the word in the manner that my friend had been misspelling it.

Is there a word that would describe this action succinctly? I had in mind,

> I had to uncorrect the spelling of glyphosate,

but the [meaning](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/uncorrect) is unrelated to this scenario, and [incorrect](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/incorrect) is only used as an adjective.

- Yes, I'm (now) aware that glyphosphate is an [acceptable alternate spelling](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83690/whats-the-difference-between-glyphosphate-and-glyphosate) of the word, albeit [much less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glyphosate%2Cglyphosphate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cglyphosate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bglyphosate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGlyphosate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGLYPHOSATE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cglyphosphate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bglyphosphate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGlyphosphate%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score -1):

- [**proscribe**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proscribe#English): To denounce.

> The word "ain't" is proscribed by many authorities.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't think that it fits what I'm looking for. I think I see where there is some confusion. In the backstory I provided, I was proscribing my friend's misspelling of the word. But that's not the action I'm trying to find a verb for. I'm trying to find a verb to explain un-doing the auto-correct from the correct spelling to the incorrect spelling.